# How to set correct maximum value for Slider in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code and I am wondering why the maximum for the first slider is 2.9 and the maximum for the second one is 2.0. Shouldn't be the maximum of the first slider be at 3.0? I don't see what I did different.

```
struct SettingsEx1View: View {
    
    @State var playSoundeffects = true
    @State var equalNotes = false
    @State var noteLength = 1.0
    @State var pauseLength = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("General")) {
                Toggle("play soundeffects", isOn: $playSoundeffects)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Exercise1")) {
                VStack {
                    Text("length of notes: \(noteLength)")
                    Slider(value: $noteLength, in: 0.1...3.0, step: 0.1)
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("length of pause: \(pauseLength)")
                    Slider(value: $pauseLength, in: 0.0...2.0, step: 0.1)
                }
                Toggle("Notes can be the same", isOn: $equalNotes)
                Text("tone difference")
                Text("waveform")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xW3v.png). Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: This is somehow joint to minValue. Looks like a bug - just set it to 0. Why do you need it 0.1?

Comment: The settings are for an exercise where you can hear two notes after another. The pause between them can be 0, but the notes need at least some time being played, so you can hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, seems to be a rounding issue – or a bug ?? This would be a fix:

```
 Slider(value: $noteLength, in: 0.1...3.01, step: 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I tried with 3.1 before, but then the maximum value would go up to 3.1.